# How to clear all Windows event log categories fast

Tags: windows-7, event-viewer

Under Windows 7 you open the Event Viewer to browse several categories. You can also clear a single category by clicking *Clear Log...* on the right pane.

Assuming I want to clear ALL categories, am I supposed to click and clear them one by one?
There are dozens of them. Is there a faster way? Maybe with PowerShell?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Try WEvtUtil.exe

There's no way via the GUI to clear all logs at once.  At least not that I've ever found. :)

### Loop and delete with intermediate file

Here's a batch file that uses [WEVTUTIL.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848) to list the logs into a text file, and then use that text file to delete each of the logs.

```
WEVTUTIL EL > .\LOGLIST.TXT
for /f %%a in ( .\LOGLIST.TXT ) do WEVTUTIL CL "%%a"
del .\LOGLIST.TXT
timeout 30
```

If you feel unsafe having this all in one batch file, then you can save this to two separate files and then run one after the other:
(The "Nuke" batch will just error out if it doesn't find a "loglist.txt" in its current directory.)

#### Populate-LogList.cmd

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Source: https://superuser.com/a/655185/389368
WEvtUtil.exe enum-logs > .\LOGLIST.TXT
```

#### Nuke-LogList.cmd

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Source: https://superuser.com/a/655185/389368
for /f %%a in ( .\LOGLIST.TXT ) do WEvtUtil.exe clear-log "%%a"
del .\LOGLIST.TXT
timeout 30
```

### Loop and delete directly

As Logman pointed out in [his answer](https://superuser.com/a/655186/23133), this can be further shortened down (and eliminate the need for the intermediate text file) by using something like (%'s double for batch file):

```
for /f %%a in ('WEVTUTIL EL') do WEVTUTIL CL "%%a"
timeout 30
```

### Run as Admin!

Whichever way you choose, ensure you "Run As Administrator".

Easiest solution I've found.  Been using it since Vista. :)

Comment: I was considering using WMI in a python script or similar - very good example of how batch can be an easier solution in certain scenarios.

Comment: [CMD output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G9OgP.png) + [Event viewer overview](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CJm8m.png). Used your second example via batch as admin. Some categories can't be cleared? Strange. And Powershell categorie still has 11.511 events? All others seem to be cleared

Comment: Screwed by a lack of quotes. sorry about that, fixed it. :)

Comment: Is it possible to use this solution or the proposed by @Logman in Windows XP? I don't see it has `wevtutil` in the system.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez "wevtutil" is only available from Vista and above... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848.aspx

Comment: @nixda I don't believe your edit is correct.  When I run the batch file against my Windows 7 64-bit machine (as I just did now), it clears those logs as well.

Comment: @techie007 That is strange. Have you used your first or second example? I'm using the second one. I cannot test the first one as I have just cleared those logs manually. All other logs were cleared. In theory there should be no difference between them.. but who knows

Comment: I'm using a slight variation of the second one, but those variations do nothing other than present prettier output, and prevent it from being run without "As Admin". :)  Just make sure you run that batch "as administrator", that's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: @techie007 I'm running it as admin. [Here is a screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnQIr.png) to proof that some categories aren't cleared. I tried the first example this time. I made a rollback until others can or cannot confirm this

Comment: @nixda It's been a few months, and apparently I forgot about this. :)  Here's some 'proof' showing it clears that Firewall log for me, no problems: http://i.imgur.com/XkAXoxc.png Not sure why it wouldn't work for you unfortunately.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 In the meantime I switched from a localized Windows to standard english MUI Windows and it appears to work for every categorie now. So, nevermind. This works

Comment: @nixda Ahh, never noticed you were using a non-English version. Perhaps there was an foreign extended character in there someplace that was throwing things off....? :)

Comment: only events with source "User Device registration" left...

Answer (score 21):

Open cmd prompt or create batch script and "run as admin":

```
for /f %x in ('wevtutil el') do wevtutil cl "%x"
```

Powershell code for clearing all event logs:

```
wevtutil el | Foreach-Object {Write-Host "Clearing $_"; wevtutil cl "$_"}
```

or pick and choose in a script:

```
wevtutil.exe cl Analytic
wevtutil.exe cl Application
wevtutil.exe cl DirectShowFilterGraph
wevtutil.exe cl DirectShowPluginControl
wevtutil.exe cl EndpointMapper
wevtutil.exe cl ForwardedEvents
wevtutil.exe cl HardwareEvents
wevtutil.exe cl Internet Explorer
wevtutil.exe cl Key Management Service
wevtutil.exe cl MF_MediaFoundationDeviceProxy
wevtutil.exe cl "Media Center"
wevtutil.exe cl MediaFoundationDeviceProxy
wevtutil.exe cl MediaFoundationPerformance
wevtutil.exe cl MediaFoundationPipeline
wevtutil.exe cl MediaFoundationPlatform
wevtutil.exe cl Microsoft-IE/Diagnostic
wevtutil.exe cl Microsoft-IEFRAME/Diagnostic
wevtutil.exe cl Microsoft-PerfTrack-IEFRAME/Diagnostic
wevtutil.exe cl Microsoft-PerfTrack-MSHTML/Diagnostic
```

etc...

You can get a complete list of all event category names by typing the following in a cmd prompt or powershell:

```
wevtutil el
```

More information can be found at [MS TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732848.aspx). Examples:

Export events from System log to C:\backup\system0506.evtx:

```
wevtutil epl System C:\backup\system0506.evtx
```

Clear all of the events from the Application log after saving them to C:\admin\backups\a10306.evtx:

```
wevtutil cl Application /bu:C:\admin\backups\a10306.evtx
```

Comment: Nice shortened version.

Comment: Works with `Microsoft Windows 11 Home` & running `powershell` as an *Admin*.

Answer (score 4):

- wevtutil is quite slow, specially when you clear all logs (including empty ones)
- fastest solution I came up with:

---

**`ForEach ( $l in ( Get-WinEvent * ).LogName | sort | get-unique ) {[System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession]::GlobalSession.ClearLog("$l")}`**

---

Resul: "Cleared 16 events in 4 logs: 0.3684785 seconds"

Each part:

- only gets logs containing events (there will be duplicate LogNames)

  ForEach ( $l in ( Get-WinEvent * ).LogName | sort | get-unique )
- clear each one

  System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession]::GlobalSession.ClearLog( "$l" )

Full function:

```
function Clear-EventLogs
{
    Begin
    {
        $t1          = ( Measure-Command -Expression{ $active = ( Get-WinEvent ).LogName } ).TotalSeconds
        $totalEvents = $active.Count
        $active      = $active | Sort | Get-Unique
        $totalLogs   = $active.Count
    }
    Process
    {
        $t2 = ( Measure-Command -Expression{
            ForEach ( $l in $active )
            {
                [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession]::GlobalSession.ClearLog( "$l" )
                # ForEach-Object { Wevtutil.exe cl "$l" }
            }
        } ).TotalSeconds
    }
    End     { $t3 = $t1 + $t2; Write-Output "Cleared $totalEvents events in $totalLogs logs: $t3 seconds" }
}
```

If you see "Get-WinEvent : The data is invalid", you've hit the undocumented hard-limit of 256 logs. It may be necessary to filter the logs first. The following will select only the logs that have events (credit to http://www.powershellish.com/blog/2015/01/19/get-winevent-max-logs/ for the diagnosis ):

```
$logs = Get-WinEvent -ListLog * | Where-Object {$_.RecordCount} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LogName
ForEach ( $l in ( Get-WinEvent $logs ).LogName | sort | get-unique ) {[System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogSession]::GlobalSession.ClearLog("$l")}
```

Comment: I retested this function. It took 271 seconds to wipe 168802 events

Comment: @nixda: 5 minutes for 169,000 events is not very fast, but I'm not sure how wevtutil would performs with the same number of events (it may also skip some of them)

Comment: Changing your original command from `Get-WinEvent *` to `Get-WinEvent -ListLog *` seems to be sufficient to resolve the "The Data is invalid" error spam and clear the logs. It took about a second to clear all the logs on my system though I did get a "Exception calling ClearLog with 1 argument: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation" error. So hopefully I didn't break anything ‍♂️

Answer (score 3):

It is important to use the delim option if you have spaces in the names:

```
WEVTUTIL EL > .\LOGLIST.TXT
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( .\LOGLIST.TXT ) do WEVTUTIL CL "%%a"
```

You can also easily disable all event logging without stopping the event log service:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('WEVTUTIL EL') do WEVTUTIL SL "%%a" /e:false
```

Of course this will only disable actually installed software events, if you install a new software, it will have the logging enabled by default. But good thing you can leave the Task Scheduler running, so just do it every month ;-)

Comment: How can I revert your second command (with SL and /e:false)? Or how can I restore all my event log properties back to default?

Comment: Dear PeterCo. I am not sure, what you mean by default. Check the documentation for the WEVTUTIL command, e.g. try to enter
        `WEVTUTIL sl /?`
at a command line.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, this clears all the Log files, which can (depending on previous settings) free up quite some space

```
WEVTUTIL EL > .\LOGLIST.TXT
for /f "delims=" %%a in ( .\LOGLIST.TXT ) do WEVTUTIL CL "%%a"
del .\LOGLIST.TXT
timeout 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used .bat files to make it a little bit easier to clear log files. Just picked the simple script here `http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-clear-the-windows-event-log-from-the-command-line/`

Copied from that link.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=1,2*" %%V IN ('bcdedit') DO SET adminTest=%%V
IF (%adminTest%)==(Access) goto noAdmin
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('wevtutil.exe el') DO (call :do_clear "%%G")
echo.
echo Event Logs have been cleared!
goto theEnd
:do_clear
echo clearing %1
wevtutil.exe cl %1
goto :eof
:noAdmin
echo You must run this script as an Administrator!
echo.
:theEnd
```

1. Open Notepad and copy-paste the that text into it.
2. Save it as a batch file and give it any name you want for example: ClEvtLog.bat or ClEvtLog.cmd.
3. Run it with admin rights.