# How do I permanently disable the Event Trigger feature in Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, task-scheduler

I'm sick of the freezing/disk access I get every time I create a new trigger while Task Scheduler scrapes all the log events together, and the feature is useless to me. Is there any way to disable that particular trigger type for good?

Failing that, is there any way to make its performance tolerable?

Comment: What happens if you clear the event logs first?

Comment: @DavidPostill: I assume if I cleared every one of the event logs, performance would be much improved. Unfortunately, this requires more effort and substantially more time every time I want to add another trigger, which I only do once every month or so at most, and furthermore wipes out log history, so I don't think that's a particularly profitable approach.

Comment: You can save the logs before you clear them. In any case are logs more than one month old really that useful? In the end it's your decision as it is a tradeoff between more work and waiting ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: It looks more like a tradeoff between waiting and more waiting + more work from here, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: [How to clear all Windows event log categories fast](http://superuser.com/q/655181) shows how to clear all the event logs from the command line. You could modify the answer to archive them first before clearing. Uses [wevutil](http://ss64.com/nt/wevtutil.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill: followup appreciated, but as previously noted, a solution that requires me to wait around before I can add a new task is just as bad as the current state of affairs. I'm looking for a one-and-done fix.